# Handling OAuth2 Implicit Redirect with Angular Routing using HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, hash-location-strategy

I'm enabling OAuth2 on an SPA as follows:

- The implicit grant type is the only grant type supported
- My Angular 5 app uses HashLocationStrategy for its routing

I cannot change either of these constraints.

When I log in to my app and get redirected, the redirect url from the authorize endpoint looks like this:

```
http://foo/#access_token=(ey...)&token_type=bearer&state=(state...)&expires_in=43199&jti=(jti...)
```

This is as expected according to the OAuth2 spec; the parameters present in the redirect url must be appended as a fragment (following the '#').

The problem I'm having is that Angular is interpreting the characters following the hash according to its hash location strategy.  It is attempting to redirect to path `access_token=...` which does not exist.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the router to cut with it's shenanigans until you're done processing the URL. Here's how:

```
imports: [
  ..
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: false }),
],
...
```

Now the nosey router will not do anything on page load. **Which means that you have to take care of it!** Go parse your OAuth state, tokens etc. Then figure out what route were you *trying* to get to (e.g. from `redirectUrl`, some part of the fragment itself, something from `localStorage` from before navigating away for auth, or similar. Once you've done that, call the router, tell it to resume:

```
this.accessToken = this.url....
this.router.navigate('wherever-you-wanted-to-go-in-the-first-place');
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem.  I went with
    @NgModule({
 imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true, initialNavigation: false})
 ],